# Package Adobe Air to Exe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, adt

Using Flash Builder 4.6, I exported an Adobe Air file from my mobile project.

I'm trying to get it packaged into an EXE (that would include the Adobe Air Runtime)

The project was compiled with Air 3.1. I looked online and there are some ADT commands that people recommend using but the problem is that the command throws errors in Air 3.1

If i use air 3.0 ADT:

```
AIR file at [app path]/app.air could not be converted.
The error was ""
```

If I use air 3.1 or air 3.2 sdk

```
SDK is missing file [my path to air]\lib\nai\bin\naip.exe
```

I'm running

```
java -jar [path to air]\lib\adt.jar" -package -target native app.dmg app.air
```

I've also tried

```
java -jar [path to air]\lib\adt.jar" -package -target native app.exe app.air
```

I've also looked into projects like this one: http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/adobe-air-2beta-2-to-exe-packaging-air-app-in-windows-executable/ , but it is for Air 2.0.

Any ideas? Apparently there is an integrated Flash Builder 4.6 tool, but for some reason the option under export release doesn't exist for mobile projects - strange...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this?  Air files -- when exported for a specific platform -- *are* executables.

If you are looking for an "installer" that will create directories, run the Air installation, and move auxiliary files to specific locations (docs, icons, etc.), then try [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

EDIT:

The code you provided works for me to create a Windows EXE.  But it seems a bit unecessary . . . why not just export the EXE file from Flash Builder ("Export Release Build" button in the top toolbar)?  If you can't or won't, then here are some suggestions:

- I am using Java version 1.6.0_29.  Make sure your Java is not only up to date, but that you are actually calling the correct version (`java -version`).
- Check the JAR directory text carefully .
- Check that you are actually calling to the right Air version.
- Make sure that the quotation marks are on both sides of the JAR path.
- You should be able to do a "Export Release Build" (though I *am* using FB 4.5).  Instead of selecting "Export as: Signed packages for each target platform", select "Export as: Signed AIR packages for installation on the desktop".  (You may have to create a certificate, but you can create one through this export feature, too.)
- (If you happen to be able to use the Flash IDE, the exported Air file has to support both "Desktop" and "Extended Desktop".)

Hopefully, this will allow you to both produce an Air program that can be converted to EXE, and actually convert it using the command line.

Comment: Well i would love to not have the user have to install Air and my application... So a packaged exe would have the air installer already in it so it would be installed with my application.

Comment: Hm . . . doesn't the installer *and* the Air app download Air automatically (well, prompted, that is), or else fail?  What is the difference?  Are you actually trying to take advantage of `NativeProcess`?

Comment: Not really. Yes it does prompt them, and unfortunately some people get scared installing air because they aren't sure what it is. compiling it into the executable installer would be preferred. sort of like how IPhone packager for Air packages air with the application.

Comment: Not to avoid answering -- I don't know why you are having the problem, and will poke around for an answer a bit -- but I think that people that you as a programmer are better served by warning/teaching people what Air is.  If you are coding for 4 different platforms, that can easily become a headache; your time is better spent coding rather than doing maintenance.

Comment: I have to agree with iND. If they wont install Air, then they don't get your program.. Simple as that. There is only so far you can cater for idiots before you have to tell them to get a clue.

Comment: I think K2xL has a valid point, actually. Being someone who not only builds software but teaches computer skills, I know a lot of people will think they downloaded the wrong thing. Those "idiots", WORMSS, actually happen to make up a good percentage of the buyers for quite a bit of software. Accommodating for such an edge case shows a lot of foresight, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old, but a co-worker just ran into the same error message using the command line tools and FlashDevelop.  It turns out that he was accidentally packaging some source files into the .air package, an extra copy of the app descriptor and one of the swc's was getting packaged in the .air file.  I removed those and repackaged the .air file, then used this command:

```
adt.bat -package -target bundle kiosk kiosk.air
```

This successfully created a captive runtime exe.  Of course there's no need to create a .air file first, you can package right to native or captive runtime, but since my co-worker was creating .air files I did it that way too just to be sure it would work.